# Mozilla Ace: text mouseover reaction

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to use Mozilla Ace with mouseover reaction on some highlighted elements. Like tooltips for the text, or, for instance, look on the color mouseover on the [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com). I want only to understand, how to make similar callback-functions in Ace and use them. So, how it can be reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is some css rules:

```
.ace_layer * {
    pointer-events:none !important;
}

.ace_constant {
    pointer-events:auto !important;
}
```

Look [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khela/VxfRj/)